# How to jump back "n" seconds from current position in video using the YouTubePlayerKit Package in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, youtube

I am very new to programming in SwiftUI (Currently running Xcode 14.2).  I am using the YouTubePlayerKit 1.3.0 Package (https://swiftpackageindex.com/SvenTiigi/YouTubePlayerKit) to load a YouTube video and play it.  One of the abilities I want to build into the app is to jump back "n" seconds in the video when a button is pushed and start playing the video from that point.  There is a function called:  getCurrentTime() that I believe returns an integer representing the elapsed time in seconds from the beginning of the video.  I want to subtract "n" seconds from that value and use the: .seek(to: , allowSeekAhead: true) function to jump to the desired location of the video based on the above calculation.  I have the code to a point where I can load the video and when I click the "SEEK" button it will jump to a static value I have hard coded into the script and play from that point.  I am struggling with how to retrieve the current time, subtract "n" seconds and use that value in the .seek() function.

This is a link to information on the YouTubePlayerKit Package: https://github.com/SvenTiigi/YouTubePlayerKit

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the SwiftUI script I have so far.  This is the description of the function I believe
will give me the time in seconds up to the current point in the video:

```
/*

/// Retrieve the elapsed time in seconds since the video started playing
/// - Parameter completion: The completion closure
func getCurrentTime(
    completion: @escaping (Result<Double, YouTubePlayerAPIError>) -> Void
)

*/



import SwiftUI
import YouTubePlayerKit

struct ContentView: View {

    let youTubePlayer = YouTubePlayer(
        source: .url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qL-ry_tz6V0"),
        configuration: .init(
            autoPlay: true
        )
    )

    @State private var JumpTo: Double = 27

    var body: some View { 
        ZStack {
            YouTubePlayerView(self.youTubePlayer) { state in
                        // Overlay ViewBuilder closure to place an overlay View
                        // for the current `YouTubePlayer.State`
                        switch state {
                        case .idle:
                            ProgressView()
                        case .ready:
                            EmptyView()
                        case .error(let error):
                            Text(verbatim: "YouTube player couldn't be loaded")
                        }
            }
            HStack {
                Button("PLAY") {
                    //Play video
                    youTubePlayer.play()
                }
                Button("PAUSE") {
                    // Pause video
                    youTubePlayer.pause()
                }
                Button("STOP") {
                    // Stop video
                    youTubePlayer.stop()
                }
                Button("SEEK") {
                    youTubePlayer.seek(to: JumpTo, allowSeekAhead: true)
                }
            }
            .offset(y: 250)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Where do you struggle? What error do you get? What does not work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @burnsi .  I tried to set the JumpTo var within the "SEEK" button action/function by calling the getCurrentTime() function like this: JumpTo = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTime() but I get an error: 'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency. Call can throw, but it is not marked with a 'try' and the error is not handled. I then tried: try JumpTo = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTime() but it gave me a different error up at the Button("SEEK") level: Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '() -> Void'

Comment: Pleae add this information to the question as code formatted text just like you did with the other one. It is very hard to read this.

Comment: I have also tried to just call the 'getCurrentTime()' function within the Button("SEEK") function like this: 
youTubePlayer.seek(to: youTubePlayer.getCurrentTime(), allowSeekAhead: true)

but get the same error as the other attempts.   So where I am struggling is why if the getCurrentTime() function returns a 'Double' wont it work when I call it in the seek(to: <int>, allowSeekAhead: <bool>) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments the culprit seems to be:

```
Button("SEEK") {
    JumpTo = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTime() // this line gives the error asnyc call and try without catch
    youTubePlayer.seek(to: JumpTo, allowSeekAhead: true)
}
```

You are in an async context here. Swift async / concurrency is a very broad field that cannot be answered in a single answer. I would recommend you put some effort into reading this stuff up.

The reason for the 2 errors are:

1. `youTubePlayer.getCurrentTime()` is a throwing function. You need to catch any possible errors and either do something with them or dismiss them. Either way the Swift compiler demands from you a certain syntax. It is called `do/catch` clause.

   ```
   do{
       try .... //throwing function
   } catch{
       // handle error here or just print it
       print(error)
   }
   ```
2. Your function is asyncronous. It means the code you write will proceed without waiting for the result of the function. To handle this you need to await it. But as your `Button("SEEK") {` method does not support something like that you have to wrap it into a `Task`:

   ```
    Task{
        await ... // await async function
    }
   ```

---

If you combine both aproaches you get....

```
Button("SEEK") {
    Task{
        do{
            JumpTo = try await youTubePlayer.getCurrentTime()
            // now you can manipulate it and do
            Jumpto = ..... 
            youTubePlayer.seek(to: JumpTo, allowSeekAhead: true)
        } catch{
           // handle error here or just print it
           print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining what a "throwing function" is and how to handle it (I will read up on that some more). Also thanks for explaining how to make an async method "wait" for a reply with that handy "Task" trick.  I will definitely read up on the async / concurrency stuff as well.